# can't prevent dragging page when touch and drag on input field jquery mobile phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova, input, preventdefault

i prevented from scrolling my cross platform app adding

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

on device ready function.
Everything works good except for input fields: when i tap on input fields and drag the page down, i can move the entire window down and see a black screen.
Any idea on how to prevent scrolling when gesture start from inside an input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting **UIWebViewBounce** to NO should fix this.

Your project > Resources > **Cordova.plist** > set:

```
UIWebViewBounce Boolean NO
```